# Calling Method and Posting Form Values Simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit

i m working on online examination i m generating student result on this end test button click

```
<button type="submit"  Value="Create" class="testBtns" style="float:right;"onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("StudentResult", "Student", new { TestId = ViewBag.TestId, style = "color:white" })'" >End Test </button>
```

i just want to submit the last answer button on the same and generate result as well how can i do so using single submit button redirecting to particular method on controller and submitting form values in database

Comment: Its not clear from your question what exactly you want to achieve. Could you please reword your problem statement. You can use snapshot to demonstrate...

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("End","StudentResult", "Student", new {  onclick = "someFunction(" + @QuesCnt + ")",TestId = 11 }) this is my action link in begin form i want to post values in form to the databse and at the same time i want to call the Student Result method from student controller

Comment: so in short my action link should behave as a submit button and as a actionlink to at the same time i hope u get it

Comment: I think it would be easier to handle this in your controller. Save the data asynchronously and redirect immediately to the view you want to show

Comment: <button type="submit"  Value="Submit Answers" class="testBtns" style="float:right;" onclick="submitClick()" @Url.Action("TestStarted", "Student", new { TestId = ViewBag.TestId,End_Time = @ViewBag.EndTime, style = "color:white" })'" >End Test </button>

Comment: do u have any idea how i can do this